# Is it possible to create a date value in Expression Language?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

Is it possible to create a date value in JSTL Expression Language (EL) without using scriptlets? Here is a snippet of some of the legacy code I'm trying to refactor to only use EL.

```
<td><%=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm z").format(new java.util.Date())%></td>
```

Apparently it prints out the current date and time. I know I can format a date using EL, but can I get a date using EL?

Comment: @BalusC great reference, thanks for the link

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in EL. But how about this, no scriptlets here

```
<jsp:useBean id="today" class="java.util.Date" scope="page" />
<fmt:formatDate value="${today}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" />
```

Comment: ah, this may be it. I'll test it out and let you know how it goes

Comment: please can you help me how to apply `${today}` with pattern i want to do this but without `substring`  `<c:forEach var="year" items="${LK_YEAR}">
                                        <c:if test="${year.year  < fn:substring(currYear,24,29)  }">
                                            <option value="${year.year}">${year.year}</option>
                                        </c:if>
                                    </c:forEach>`

Comment: Is "Today" the date on the server side or the client side in this case? I would think Server

Comment: @njfife today is on server side as all JSPs are executed on the server

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it is even possible to get the client side date from a JSP, you would have to do it in the Java script... oh well

Answer (score 1):

Thid would be helpfull if you use spring webflow framework

if you define this on the flow.xml

```
<on-start>
    <set name="flowScope.now" value="new java.util.Date()" />
</on-start>
```

You can get the value like this

```
<fmt:formatDate value="#{now}" pattern="MM.dd.yyyy" />
```