# Checking date in EL

Tags: jsp, date, el

Is it possible to to check / compare the value of a `Date` object in JSP, using EL only? I'm making a web application using Spring MVC + JSP and I'm passing an object of `Date` class to JSP in the controller using

```
model.addAttribute("date", randomDate);
```

In JSP I would like to check, if the `date` has a certain value. Specifically I would need to check for a certain year, month and day, in the spirit of

```
<c:if test="${date == '1.1.2014'}">
    <span>Happy new Year!</span>
</c:if>
```

Is there a straightforward way to inspect the value of `Data` type variable using EL, or JSTL function? I would like to avoid scriptlets, if possible.

Comment: Why don't you do the check in the controller?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am currently doing it that way, but it's not very nice, as it only determines the styling of the element, so I was wondering if there is a way of doing it directly in JSP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a date value in Expression Language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512682/is-it-possible-to-create-a-date-value-in-expression-language). Create the desired date in page context, then compare it with your date object from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" value="${date}" var="formatedDate" />
<c:if test="${formatedDate == '01-01-2014'}">
    <span>Happy new Year!</span>
</c:if>
```